# Wix custom action behavior gets invoked inconsistently on different windows server

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, patch, windows-server-2019

I have an issue where I have some custom action defined in wix project.
We are creating patch for our product. To create patch, when we build the code to generate msi on win server 2008 then upon installing patch the custom action doesn't get invoked(expected behaviour) but when we build the same code to generate msi on win server 2019 then the custom action is getting invoked.

The custom action is defined to update some ini file. Hence ini file is getting modified upon installing the patch.(which should not happen)

When I check the difference between the msi generated on 2008 and 2019 then i could see only below difference.

[image]

I checked the difference between the tools installed on 2008 and 2019, i found there is difference in wix toolset version on both the machine(2008 has 3.11.0.1528 and 2019 has 3.11.2.4516)

can someone please let me know what could cause such issue?
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check **InstallUISequence** and **InstallExecuteSequence** table for the problematic custom action in msi file. Look for the **Condition** of the custom action. Somehow, the condition evaluating true in Server 2019. You need to debug msi log to find the root cause.

Comment: I debug the patch log, found this
Action WriteIniValues. Writing INI files values
Executing op:IniFilePath(File=myfile.ini,Folder=C:\mypath)
Executing op:IniWriteRemoveValue(Section=Data,Key=Server,Value=myserver,Mode=0)
WriteIniValues: File: myfile.ini,  Section: Data,  Key: Server, Value: myserver
Executing op:IniWriteRemoveValue(Section=Data,Key=Databasename,,Mode=0)
WriteIniValues: File: myfile.ini,  Section: Data,  Key: Databasename, Value: 
Executing op: IniWriteRemoveValue(Section=Data,Key=Username,,Mode=0)
WriteIniValues: File: myfile.ini,  Section: Data,  Key: Username, Value:

Comment: See here, the ini file values are getting removed by writing empty values. However, for database server section, the value preserves.

Comment: What are the conditions of WriteIniValues custom action for both 2008 and 2019 server msi files?

Comment: Installed AND (NOT REMOVE="ALL") this is the condition.

Comment: In msi file, I could not see on what condition it is executing. The above condition I have given from my project wix.

Comment: Condition "Installed AND (NOT REMOVE="ALL")" means it allows execution during patch. For not invoking while applying patch, condition should be
"Installed AND Not PATCH AND (Not REMOVE="ALL")"

Comment: Then how it is working in win server 2008?
Is there a way i can connect to discuss further on this ?

Comment: WriteIniValues action might be running on 2008 as well but not corrupting the .ini file. You can check log file for this custom action on 2008 server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248467/discussion-between-vivek-jaiswal-and-nihal-kumar).